# Bootstrap 4 navbar bug

Tags: html, css

So as you can see in the code snippet, the background of the dropdown menu jumps up. However when I delete the .navlinks-center class it works just fine.

I am new to web development and would really appreciate some help, because I can't get it fixed without changing the position of the navlinks.

```css
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95) !important;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.45s ease;
    z-index: 1030; 
}

.navlinks-center {
position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body style=" background-color: gray;"
  >
  
 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom Schatten navbar-expand-xl navbar-light justify-content-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Brand1.png" style="height: 3.6rem;"></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Brand2.png" style="height: 3rem;"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navlinks-center">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="about.html">Über uns</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="events.html">Events</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="forum.html">Forum</a>
          </li>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As suggested below I tried text align instead and now it works fine  on small screens, but on a large screen the nav-items align to the left.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body style=" background-color: gray;"
  >
  
 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom Schatten navbar-expand-xl navbar-light justify-content-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Brand1.png" style="height: 3.6rem; width: 108px;"></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Brand2.png" style="height: 3rem; width: 261px;"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navlinks-center">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="about.html">Über uns</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="events.html">Events</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link hvr-grow" href="forum.html">Forum</a>
          </li>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine with small screens now, but on a large screen the nav-items align on the left next to the brands

Comment: `navlinks-center` is your custom css, why do you want `position: absolute` here?

Comment: tbh I am not 100% sure why I put it there and it would probably make sense to delete it, but it somehow moves the content below if I do so. I will remove it later

Answer (score 0):

Is "position:absolute" necessary?

Because I think you can achieve your goal by simply using "text-align" or "margin" properties.

For example :

```
       .navbar-custom {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95) !important;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transition: all 0.45s ease;
            z-index: 1030; 
        }

        .navbar-collapse{
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Or

```
       .navbar-custom {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95) !important;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transition: all 0.45s ease;
            z-index: 1030; 
        }

        .nav-item {
            margin: auto;
        }
```

**[EDIT]**

To keep the menu centered and the pictures on the left (like in your example), you may need to use media queries. If your brand pictures have a constant width, here is a css that should work :

```
    .navbar-custom {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95) !important;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transition: all 0.45s ease;
            z-index: 1030;
        }

        .nav-item{
            margin: auto;
        }
        .navbar-nav{
            display: flex;
            margin: auto;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:1200px){
            .navbar-nav{
                padding-right: 6.6rem;
            }
        }
```

But I'm still not sure it is the best solution.

Comment: Good Idea, the problem is that I use 2 pictures in the navbar and they push the text to the right when I just use text-align: center.

Comment: Do you want the brand pictures to be on the left and the menu always centered ?

Comment: On a 1920x1080 px display yes. Bit smaller will get you the brands next to each other with a dropdown next to it. On Phones the brands are above each other with the dropdown on the bottom.

Comment: I will try these solutions. The Problem seems to be that text align and auto margin work on small screens, but on a desktop the text aligns to the left